# Linq query with Average

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have 3 tables:

```
tblCompany : Id, Name, Location 
tblRating  : Id, CompanyId, Rate 
tblImages  : Id, CompanyId, ImagePath
```

I have a class

```
public class Company
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string AverageRate { get; set; }
    public List<string> ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

I want a LINQ query to produce a result to match the `Company` class.

I wrote this query but it does not work

```
        List<Company>  result = null;

        using (DataContext dc = new DataContext())
        {
            result = (from a in dc.GetTable<tblCompany>()
                      join b in dc.GetTable<tblRating>()
                      on a.Id equals b.CompanyId
                      join c in dc.GetTable<tblImages>()
                      on a.Id equals c.CompanyId

                      select new SearchResult
                      {
                          CompanyName = a.Company,
                          Location = a.Location,
                          AverageRate = b.Rate.Average(),
                          ImagePath = c.ImagePath.ToList()

                      }).ToList<Company>();
        }
```

Comment: what type is your Rate in tblRating? is it a int, float, string, etc..?

Comment: @MarcelB it is a decimal

Comment: @DanielS i wrote a Linq query for it , but it didnt work the way i want it because of the average and the tblImages tables

Comment: @juharr on companyId Column

Comment: @Jmocke You should include what you tried, what the results were and what you expected.

Comment: @juharr ok then let me edit the post

Comment: Why is `AverageRate` a `string` instead of a `decimal`?

Comment: @juharr i want to display it as string but i can leave it decimal then use ToString() method to convert it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited for whole Query:

(I've to say i'm sorry but i have no way of testing this query yet)

You can use the [let clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) instead of the joins:

```
var result = (from c in dc.GetTable<tblCompany>()

              let r = (from re in dc.GetTable<tblRating>()
                       where re.CompanyId == c.Id && re.Rate != null
                       select re.Rate)

              let i = (from im in dc.GetTable<tblImages>()
                       where im.CompanyId == c.Id
                       select im.ImagePath)

              select new SearchResult
              {
                  CompanyName = c.Name,
                  Location = c.Location,
                  AverageRate = r.Average(),
                  ImagePath = i.ToList()
              }).ToList<Company>();
```

Comment: You do realize you can just use `Average` instead of `Sum` and `Count`.

Comment: @MarcelB what about the others fields, how can i get them ??

Comment: I've seen now that you've wrote your query-try in your question. i've edited my Answer to fit your Question

Comment: @MarcelB when a company does not have a rating, the query throws an error

Comment: @MarcelB error message: Null can not be assigned to a member System.Decimal type because it is a non- nullable value type.

Comment: then the where from the let r should be Extended to catch nulls --> where re.CompanyId == c.Id && re.Rate != null .. would be my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
result = (from a in dc.GetTable<tblCompany>()
                      join b in dc.GetTable<tblRating>()
                      on a.Id equals b.CompanyId
                      join c in dc.GetTable<tblImages>()
                      on a.Id equals c.CompanyId
                      group new { b.Rate, c.ImagePath}
                      by new { a.Id, a.Location,a.Name} into groupList
                      select new Company
                      {
                          CompanyName = groupList.Key.Name,
                          Location = groupList.Key.Location,
                          AverageRate = groupList.Average(a=>a.Rate),
                          ImagePath = groupList.Select(i=>i.ImagePath).ToList()

                      }).ToList<Company>();
```

Comment: can you handle the case when a company does not have a rating and also take only the 5 first ImagePath

Comment: yes, you can use left join on Rating table, also use `.Take(5)` after `.ToList()` on image path to get max 5 image paths.